# Java string to double conversion

Tags: java, jdbc, double

I've been reading up on the net about the issues with handling `float` and `double` types in java. Unfortunately, the image is still not clear. Hence, i'm asking here direct. :(

My `MySQL` table has various `DECIMAL(m,d)` columns. The `m` may range from 5 to 30. `d` stays a constant at 2.

### Question 1.

What equivalent data-type should i be using in Java to work (i.e store, retrieve, and process) with the size of the values in my table? (I've settled with double - hence this post).

### Question 2.

While trying to parse a double from a string, i'm getting errors

```
Double dpu = new Double(dpuField.getText());
```

for example -

```
"1" -> java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
"10" -> 1.0
"101" -> 10.0
"101." -> 101.0
"101.1" -> 101.0
"101.19" -> 101.1
```

What am i doing wrong? What is the correct way to convert a string to a double value?
And what measures should i take to perform operations on such values?

### EDIT

This is the code -

```
    System.out.println(dpuField.getText());
    Double dpu = new Double(dpuField.getText());
    System.out.println(dpu);
```

Yes, the problem lies with `getText()` reporting the wrong value of the `dpuField`.
This method is called on the `JTextField keyTyped` event. So what's going wrong here?

### EDIT 2

Looking at : 
http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/post1.0/ui/keylistener.html
Apparently, `keyTyped()` does not give me the keycode. I'll have to switch to `keyRealeased()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *What equivalent data-type should i be using in Java to work (i.e store, retrieve, and process) with the size of the values in my table? (I've settled with double - hence this post).*

Since it's a `DECIMAL` field, you should [prefer](http://floating-point-gui.de/) [`java.math.BigDecimal`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). You can store it in DB using [`PreparedStatement#setBigDecimal()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBigDecimal%28int,%20java.math.BigDecimal%29) and you can retrieve it from DB using [`ResultSet#getBigDecimal()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29).

> *While trying to parse a double from a string, i'm getting errors*

This can't be true. The problem lies somewhere else. Maybe it is just not returning the data you expect to be returned or you are not using/debugging the values you expect them to be.

Comment: Use [`JFormattedTextField`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html). See [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html).

Answer (score 4):

1. if you need exact precision without rounding errors, you should use a [`BigDecimal`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).
2. Your code looks OK - could it be that `dpuField.getText()` somehow cuts the last character from the string values you list above?

**Update**: you say

> Yes, the problem lies with `getText()` reporting the wrong value of the `dpuField`. This method is called on the `JTextField` `keyTyped` event.

Could it be that `getText()` returns the value of the field *before* the last typed key is actually appended to it?

Comment: but isn't getText() called AFTER the keyTyped event occurs? Meaning that the last typed character is already on the textfield. Puzzling. :@ Anyway, i think the major problem is solved here. :)

Comment: here we go. It becomes clear here http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/post1.0/ui/keylistener.html

Answer (score 1):

For decimal, I believe you risk losing precision if you don't use a `BigDecimal` on the Java side, as some decimal fractions can't be stored as a binary fraction.

Prefer `Double.valueOf(String)` over the constructor, but that's a valid way.  Something else must be going on (i.e. I doubt those are the actual String values you're passing in).

Answer (score 1):

Question1: It's bad idea to map DECIMAL columns to Double, usually the `BigDecimal` is the correct type. http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html#1055175

Question 2: You are doing something wrong; print the String value before converting.