# how to convert a String to double [] []

Tags: java, type-conversion

How do I convert 
`String data ="[{1,1},{0,0}]"`
to 
`double [][] data = new double[][]{{1,1},{0,0}}`

in java

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to double conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950529/java-string-to-double-conversion)

Comment: Would that be some json input? If you are always going to get 4 doubles with the same set of parenthesis and separators, may a regexp be a quick solution?

Comment: @dotvav ... it can vary, but the format is always same... this is coming from HTTP get method

Answer (score 1):

If you need a flexible solution, a java.util.StringTokenizer should do it:

```
StringTokenizer scanner = new StringTokenizer(data, "[]{},", true);
```

You can parse a variable number of double tuples and also the tuple size is flexible (even different sizes are possible).